# Iterative solution for generating all permutations of a string

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, combinatorics, complexity

I know the runtime for generating all permutations is supposed to be \$O(n!)\$. I'm not sure if the code I wrote for it runs in \$O(n!)\$ though. I'm having trouble analyzing its runtime.

The `for(char c: cArray)` part is in \$O(n)\$. What about `for (String s: currResults)` and `for (int i = 0; i < s.length() + 1; i++)`?

```
public static Set<String> getPermutations(String str) {
        char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();
        Set<String> realRes = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
        for (char c : cArray) {
            Set<String> currResults = new HashSet<String>(results);
            String charToAdd = String.valueOf(c);
            results.add(charToAdd);
            for (String s : currResults) {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length() + 1; i++) {
                    String newWord = s.substring(0, i) + charToAdd + s.substring(i);
                    if (newWord.length() == str.length()) {
                        realRes.add(newWord);
                    }
                    else {
                        results.add(newWord);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return realRes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Time complexity analysis

Let's think about what this does.

> ```
>         for (char c : cArray) {
> ```

This says that for each character in the string (since `cArray` is the character array view of the string), we iterate once.  As you note, this is \$O(n)\$ where \$n\$ is the number of characters in the string.

> ```
>         Set<String> currResults = new HashSet<String>(results);
> ```

This is \$O(m)\$ where \$m\$ is the number of entries in the `Set`.  Note that that will change as you go.

> ```
>         String charToAdd = String.valueOf(c);
>         results.add(charToAdd);
> ```

This takes constant time.

> ```
>         for (String s : currResults) {
> ```

This takes \$O(m)\$ time again.

> ```
>             for (int i = 0; i < s.length() + 1; i++) {
> ```

This takes \$O(l)\$ time, where \$l\$ is the length of this string.  Again, this will change over time.

> ```
>                 String newWord = s.substring(0, i) + charToAdd + s.substring(i);
> ```

This takes \$O(l)\$ time, as it involves copying `s` to a new string.

> ```
>                 if (newWord.length() == str.length()) {
>                     realRes.add(newWord);
>                 }
>                 else {
>                     results.add(newWord);
>                 }
> ```

This takes constant time.

We do \$n\$ iterations of the outer loop.

First iteration

\$n\$ is the number of characters in `str` and will be throughout.

\$m\$ is 0.  We haven't put any entries in the set yet.

\$l\$ doesn't exist.  We never get to that section of code.

We end with one entry in `results` and no entries in `realRes`.

Second iteration

\$m\$ is 1.

\$l\$ is 1.

We end with three entries in `results` and no entries in `realRes`.

Third iteration

\$m\$ is 3.  This is 2 + 1.

\$l\$ ranges from 2 to 1.

We end with nine entries in `results` and no entries in `realRes`.

Fourth iteration

\$m\$ is 9.  This is 3 * 2 + 2 + 1.

\$l\$ ranges from 3 to 1.

We end with forty entries in `results` and no entries in `realRes`.

nth iteration

We end with \$n!\$ entries in `realRes`.  We add increasing numbers of strings to `results`, equal to \$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i!\$.  Note that that is less than \$n!\$.

Note that this assumes that all the characters in the string are different.  If some characters repeat, this will exaggerate the number of entries.  Of course, for Big-O notation, that's fine.  So we can say that overall this is still \$O(n!)\$.

#### Alternately styled code

```
    public static Set<String> getPermutations(String str) {
        Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> partials = new HashSet<>();
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            List<String> current = new ArrayList<>();
            String charToAdd = String.valueOf(c);
            for (String s : partials) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); i++) {
                    String newWord = s.substring(0, i) + charToAdd + s.substring(i);
                    if (newWord.length() == str.length()) {
                        results.add(newWord);
                    } else {
                        current.add(newWord);
                    }
                }
            }

            partials.add(charToAdd);
            partials.addAll(current);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

I don't like the name `results` for what you had.  It's not results.  It's partial permuations.  So I changed it to `partials`.

With the name `results` available, I'd prefer that to `realRes`.

I find it easier to read if we do the `toCharArray` in the `for` loop itself.  That way I don't have to look around to find what `cArray` is.

Rather than copy the entire set to another set on every iteration, I'd rather just copy the things that I'm adding.  So I made a `List` for that purpose.  That (and moving the `charToAdd` `add`) allows us to loop directly over `partials` rather than the new collection.

We can save a math operation if we say `i <= s.length()` rather than `i < s.length() + 1`.  I also find it a bit clearer about what it is doing.

The Java standard is to do the fully cuddled `else`.  It's not a big deal if you do it the other way, but I changed that on my way through.